# Location of manage.py file for django-disqus

Tags: django

Everything on the install of django-disqus has gone smooth till now.

I ran manage.py as instructed to here: http://django-disqus.readthedocs.org/en/latest/commands.html but the output was all wrong because I ran the dumpdata command on the wrong manage.py file.

```
./manage.py dumpdata
```

Where is the manage.py file I'm to run dumpdata on?

I'm attempting to setup the dump as a .json so that the comments are pulled locally as seen here: http://docs.disqus.com/help/58 It keeps a backup and is good for seo.

Comment: If you're just trying to install it, you shouldn't need to dumpdata. Just follow the directions [here](http://django-disqus.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#configuring-your-django-installation)

Comment: Looks like you found a typo in the docs. They forgot the `disqus_` before the `dumpdata` in their example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs you linked are to custom management commands that django disqus adds...

You use the project's `./manage.py`, but now it has added functionality by typing:

```
./manage.py disqus_dumpdata
```

Comment: I ran 'disqus_dumpdata' but received the error 'urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: BAD REQUEST'. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to dump the data from your already setup disqus comments? or are you trying to setup disqus? Disqus stores the comments on their servers and you are trying to request it from them. If you haven't setup an account and started posting comments, you don't need to use that management command

Comment: I'm attempting to setup the dump as a .json so that the comments are pulled locally as seen here: http://docs.disqus.com/help/58/  It keeps a backup and is good for seo.

Comment: so you are able to post comments already? i'll take another look

Comment: Yea, I can post just fine. This last step is killing me.

Comment: Are you posting to a live account or in testing mode (disqus dev 1)

Comment: Dev 1, but would that cause the 400 error I'm receiving when attempting to run disqus_dumpdata?